# Print specific columns and the rest of the columns

Tags: awk

This is my current input:

```
12 01 2016   "TEST-12345" "Bug"  12 01 2016   "Here are some words with spaces" "No" "No"
```

At the moment I'm using this command:

```
cat DATEI | awk '{print $3"."$2"."$1,$4,$5,$8"."$7"."$6}'
```

but I won't get the last columns `"Here are some words with spaces" "No" "No"`. Sure, I can do `$9,$10,$11,$12,$13...$100` but this isn't a nice solution.

My aim is it to get the following output:

```
2016.01.12 "TEST-12345" "Bug" 2016.1.12 "Here are some words with spaces" "No" "No"
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Show us your input and the awk command you're using to get your current output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F '"' -v OFS='"' '{split($1, a, " ");$1=a[3]"."a[2]"."a[1]" ";$5=" "$1;print $0}'
```

Use `"` as `IFS` and `OFS` and split the first field `$1` with separator as white space to array a. And reassign the $1 with repositioned value using values in array `a`. Do the same for `$5` also. Here i assumed `$5` is same as `$1` else use another split for `$5`.

Comment: ...or just `print` instead of `print $0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check for date-like strings and you don't have other dates you don't want to convert in the text, you could just use sed:

```
sed -E -e 's/([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{4})/\3.\2.\1/g' DATEI
```

Use `-r` instead of `-E` for GNU sed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new into scripting ;-) ...is it already the ready-to-paste-syntax or....?

Comment: if `cat DATE | awk {whatever}` was working for you, you should be able to paste my sed code unchanged.

Comment: It doesn't work :-( With awk '{print $3"."$2"."$1,$4,$5,$8"."$7"."$6}' I get every column except "Here are some words with spaces" "No" "No". The "Here are some words with spaces"-column has not the same length everytime. The date is already correct but I "only" need to print the rest of columns after ...$6.

Comment: The sed script above will change all the 12 01 2016 dates to 2016.01.12 and keep the rest of the line the same. Perhaps you have tabs between the date sections instead of spaces? Also give more detail on what "it doesn't work" means - is there an error or incorrect output?

Comment: cat DATEI | sed -E -e 's/([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{4})/\3.\2.\1/g' DATEI I got an error: sed: invalid option -- 'E' and if I remove -E the following message appears: sed: -e expression #1, char 63: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @der_fux in gnu sed use -r instead of -E

Comment: Also, you don't need that `cat`. I'm running sed on the DATE file already.